# How to pass dataframes into temp tables for airflow tasks

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

So I have a piece of code that has multiple functions in python for a workstream that we have developed. This workstream takes a CSV and passes it through a data-frame. This data-frame is then passed through multiple functions which apply various transformation to the dataframe.

However, when writing this code into a airflow environment , due to the way dataframes work in a virtual environment and having data run across multiple machines, I wont be able to pass through my dataframes through each function and will have to store them somewhere?

Does anyone know how to set up a temp table in bigquery for passing through a dataframe for each of my functions so i can run my ETL for them all using my airflow tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Airflow task to start from dataframe input then you are using it wrong. If you want to execute your script as one unit you can use `PythonOperator` or `BashOperator` however if you want to break the code into multiple tasks you probably need to do some refactoring.

To create a `BigQuery` external table from a `csv` on `GCS` you can set `external_table` in `GCSToBigQueryOperator` as:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
load_csv = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='gcs_to_bigquery_example',
        bucket='cloud-samples-data',
        source_objects=['bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv'],
        destination_project_dataset_table=f"{DATASET_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}",
        schema_fields=[
            {'name': 'name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
            {'name': 'post_abbr', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        ],
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        external_table=True,
    )
```

I don't know what is the functionality of the dataframes in your workflow (I assume it's to do some kind of transformation on the `csv`) for that you can use `GCSFileTransformOperator` (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c6c662798b3cdee88a760cfeccd1be83ec7922f2/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/gcs.py#L559)). This operator copies data from a source GCS location to a temporary location on the local filesystem. Runs a transformation on this file as specified by
the transformation script and uploads the output to a destination bucket. If the output bucket is not specified the original file will be overwritten.

So possible your workflow can be:

1. File land in GCS
2. Run `GCSFileTransformOperator` to process and clean the records.
3. Create a table in BigQuery with `GCSToBigQueryOperator`

Comment: So this makes since to do but would it be the best solution as with the csv transformation, with each function, columns are being dropped, names of columns are being changed, columns are being added and removed etc. And appending to a data frame table with column parameters are change might lead to a issue when uploading to big query as the schema is always in flux.

Comment: @MizanurChoudhury That depends on your specific ETL. You can also clean what you can before you dump the raw csv to GCS. This is more of a question of which component you have control over and where you can make changes. These are all big questions though - This is a design of a whole process which is out of scope of a StackOverflow question.